# Geocoder in a fragment error

Tags: java, android

Im trying to create a Geocoder in a fragment. In this way

```
Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
```

I get an error that Geocoder (android.content.Context, Locale) in Geocoder cannot be applied to (.Fragment_1, Locale)

It works perfectly in an Activity but not in a Fragment. Any support will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: please post the full error log to help you in a better way. :)

Comment: @Chefes My apologies I managed to fix the error, I included getActivity(), Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(getActivity, Locale.ENGLISH). Im a beginner so its my first time working with fragments. Thanks